# PHP web page "translated" to Python web app

Tags: php, python, translation

**I was wondering if this (my 'index.php') single page downloading website (I made) could be "translated" to a python web app ('get.py').**

Here is the PHP from 'index.php':

```
<?php
    echo '
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" class="text" placeholder="URL" name="url">
            <input type="submit" class="submit" name="Submit" value="Get Link">
        </form>
    ';
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        $url = $_POST['url'];
        echo '<br><a href="http://'.$url.'" download>Download</a><br>';
    }
?>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What framework are you going to use in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny reading this question I asked 5 years ago, but I'm here to answer my own question now for any other junior devs who may have been learning PHP like me, and wanted to tackle "converting" something basic like this to a more "modern" approach. 
At the time of asking this question I was very new to web development and didn't know what I wanted or needed. I'd only been told Python was preferable over PHP, although that their *opinion*, and I was too fresh for any critical thinking on the subject. 
Like PHP, Python is a back-end language (which means it's executed on the server, not the browser). So technically speaking, you could achieve this using a python framework such as [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) or [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/). 
However, as [bpow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4777949/bpow) suggested:

> I would recommend using Javascript to handle this instead of Python. Python is a purely backend language, whereas Javascript has nearly identical syntax as PHP. If you were to try to do this with Python, you'd also have to use Javascript to handle the frontend.

JavaScript would be better suited in this case as there's really no need to contact the server for something we can do entirely in the browser.

My suggestion would be to pick up a JavaScript framework and use that. I would recommend [VueJS](https://vuejs.org/) because it is open source and super easy to get started, you just have to include the CDN `<script>` tag in the HTML `<head>`. Here's an idea of how it would look in VueJS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Download Link Generater</title>

    <!-- development version, includes helpful console warnings -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <input type="text" v-model='link_to_download' placeholder="Enter URL of asset you wish to download">
        <a v-bind:href='link_to_download' download>Download {{ link_to_download }}</a>
    </div>

    <script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            link_to_download: '' // This is updated by the text input because it is bound by the 'v-model' attribute. When this changes, it also updates everywhere it is used in the DOM, so here being the href url and the text in the <a> hyperlink.
        }
    })
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Because Vue is a *reactive* framework, the text input updates the `link_to_download` variable in the `data` hook as you type. As the variable in the `data` hook changes (via the `v-model` binding), everywhere in the DOM that variable is used *reacts* to the changing variable and mirrors it, eliminating the need of a backend server to "generate" the download link.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Javascript to handle this instead of Python. Python is a purely backend language, whereas Javascript has nearly identical syntax as PHP. If you were to try to do this with Python, you'd also have to use Javascript to handle the frontend.